# opengl es projection and camera in android

Tags: android, opengl-es, projection

iam new to android opengl es programming. I have learned to create 3d objects and to view them on screen using APIDemos in android sdk. but, i cannot understand the projection call glFrustumf(..) and how to set up the camera. I will be pleased if any one explains how the glFrustumf(..) works.

Answer (score 2):

[Chapter 3 of the OpengGL Red Book](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter03.html#name3) has a very good explanation on how to set up a camera and its view frustum in OpengGL.

[image: the view frustum]

I would also suggest that you experiment with the [Nate Robins OpenGL tutorials](http://user.xmission.com/~nate/tutors.html), especially with the projection tutorial:

[image: projection tutorial]